# get user specific ID on IOS

Tags: ios

I want to make an IOS app that has information like a task list for a user that syncs across all of their devices - but I hate apps that make you login to something - I'm looking for some id that connects the *user* - I know you can get the device ID, but hoping more for something like reading the current app store id or something.

Bottom line what I'm trying to achieve is that if someone adds some data on their iphone, it's available on their ipad.   Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

> Bottom line what I'm trying to achieve is that if someone adds some data on their iphone, it's available on their ipad. Any idea how to do that?

Yes, it's called iCloud. You just make an app that syncs up into iCloud. No login within the app is required; the user has to be signed into iCloud on their device, but most users are. If you look at Apple's own apps, that is what they are doing; look, for example, at how a Reminders list or a change in Contacts is reflected automatically onto all the user's devices. That's iCloud in action.